# gnome terminal crash and silent exit - running python3/nvidia RAPIDS 22.04

Tags: command-line, python, gnome-terminal

I'm running a python program (machine learning training) under conda on 22.04 that uses RAPIDS GPU - in the middle of a large run it sometimes completely silently exists and kills the tmux and gnome terminal it's running in. I've tried running under GDB but that also gets killed. How do I debug what's going on?

Comment: Check `/var/log/syslog` around the time it happens ..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using distributed tracing (via OTel) to debug? Here's a good place to start  [Distributed tracing](https://gethelios.dev/distributed-tracing/)